# How to define Flow log output file

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am playing around with [flow](https://flow.org)

I am unable to redefine the path to log file.
Now logs go to `Logs will go to /private/tmp/flow/zSUserszSkurumkanzSWorkzSbmpsitezSsrc.log`

How to customize the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can customize the flow log location in your `.flowconfig` (this file is [created when you run `flow init`](https://flow.org/en/docs/usage/#toc-initialize-your-project)).

use the `options` section with [the `log.file` attribute](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-log-file-string), like so:

```
[options]
log.file=/var/log/flow/my.log
```

by default, logs will be written to an internally-defined temporary directory. from the [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-log-file-string):

> #### `log.file (string)`
>
> The path to the log file (defaults to `/tmp/flow/<escaped root path>.log`).